# Parameter is not valid - error when sending a bitmap via TCP with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, file-transfer

I have a file transfer program. The program (Client) does following operations to send a bitmap via TCP socket: get screenshot -> **grab Bitmap from memory** -> convert to stream -> send

```
        MemoryStream Fs = new MemoryStream();

//////////////11111
        Bitmap bmp = TakeScreen();

///////////////2222
        //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\temp\001.bmp");


        bmp.Save(Fs, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        Byte[] buffer = Fs.ToArray();

        Fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        TcpClient socket = new TcpClient("192.168.0.131", 1095);

        NetworkStream nw = socket.GetStream();
        nw.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        nw.Close();
        Fs.Dispose();
        socket.Close();
        bmp.Dispose();
```

- If I choose to transfer image directly from memory - no errors.
- If I try to load Bitmap from file first - getting "Parameter is not valid" error on a server's side.

here is the server side:

```
                    NetworkStream Nw = new NetworkStream(handlerSocket.Client);
                    int thisRead = 0;
                    int Blocksize = 1024;
                    Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[Blocksize];

                    Bitmap screen = getScreen(Nw, dataByte, thisRead, Blocksize);
                    Nw.Close();
```

and

```
   private Bitmap getScreen(NetworkStream Nw, Byte[] dataByte, int thisRead, int Blocksize)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        using (var strm = new MemoryStream())
        {

            while (true)
            {
                thisRead = Nw.Read(dataByte, 0, Blocksize);
                strm.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
                if (thisRead == 0)
                    break;
            }

            bitmap = new Bitmap(strm); // Error here
        }
        Bitmap bm3 = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        bitmap.Dispose();
        return bm3;
    }
```

**What's causing this error?** I guess it has something to do with the MemoryStream.

**edit: simplified the question**

Comment: You should really change the TCP communication to include the size of the binary information you're transmitting. Currently the server may not have the full bitmap information before it is trying to create the bitmap. Send the size of the bitmap as `long` for example before you send the bitmap information. That way, the server knows how many bytes to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to seek to the beginning of the stream before you can create the `Bitmap` in `getScreen`.

```
private Bitmap getScreen(NetworkStream Nw, Byte[] dataByte, int thisRead, int Blocksize)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (var strm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            thisRead = Nw.Read(dataByte, 0, Blocksize);
            strm.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
            if (thisRead == 0)
               break;
        }

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin; // <-- Go Back to beginning of stream
        bitmap = new Bitmap(strm); // Error here
    }
    Bitmap bm3 = new Bitmap(bitmap);
    bitmap.Dispose();
    return bm3;
}
```

**EDIT**
Detailed explanation: After writing the last byte to the stream, the stream's current position is a the end of the stream. Creating a `Bitmap` from the screen now tries to read the bitmap from the stream, which doesn't work, as there is no more data after the current position (= the end of the stream).

So what you need to do is tell the stream to set the current position back to the beginning of the stream. Then, the bitmap information can be read.

Comment: I've added "strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);" as you suggested, but the same error occurs at the same line.. I'm not sure if the problem that you've explained is the case, because I can send images from memory just fine, without the need of using Seek()

Comment: The code you wrote to obtain the bitmap as bytes is also strange. You're writing the bitmap to a memory stream. Then you get the memory stream's byte buffer (which already contains the bytes for the bitmap) and *after that* you read the stream *again*, which is redundant. Maybe you are now victim to what I wrote in my comment to the question, which is: are you sure that the entire bitmap is transferred to the server before the server tries to create the bitmap? Have you tried storing the received content to a file and open it with Paint?`

Comment: niiice.. you probably didn't notice it, but your post just now helped to solve my problem once and for all.. As you said, I used to "Read" the stream 2 times in a row, so I commented out "//Fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);", and for my surprise - image transfer worked flawlessly! I don't know why transfer directly from "memory" worked even with the stream's "second read"... On a side note, yes, I opened images in Paint, Xnview, etc.. sizes, dimensions, colors were exactly the same on the Client and Server. Anyway, problem solved, thank You for your advice @Thorsten Dittmar !